# How to mock a private property in controller correctly?

Tags: apex, unit-test, apexmock

I have a controller with a private property that holds an instance of an object. The code below is reduced from unnecessary details.

```
public with sharing class BarController
{
    private Foo fooProperty;

    public BarController()
    {
        fooProperty = new Foo();
    }

    public void doSomeStuff()
    {
        fooProperty.someAction();
    }

}
```

I am using the [**fflib-apex-mocks**](https://github.com/financialforcedev/fflib-apex-mocks) mocking framework in my unit tests. I am quite curious about what is the correct way to mock a private property in a controller? I admit there can be several right ways to do this and it would be good to know all them, so I hope this question is not too broad.

One way I am considering is use the `@TestVisible` annotation for the private property and inject it in a unit test.

```
public with sharing class BarController
{
    @TestVisible
    private Foo fooProperty;

    public BarController()
    {
        fooProperty = new Foo();
    }

    ....

}
```

and in test:

```
@isTest
public class BarControllerTest
{
    @isTest
    static void testController()
    {
        BarController cntrl = new BarController();

        // Create mockFoo
        .....

        cntrl.fooProperty = mockFoo;

        // Perform test

    }
}
```

My main concern here is that the constructor of `BarController` will be executed anyways, which might require a developer to setup data for `new Foo();` for it to execute successfully. Consequently, it doesn't untie a unit test for `BarController` from the need to initialize data for `Foo`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach I've used is to have two constructors, one of which is `private @TestVisible` and which accepts the injected object as its parameter. The primary, public constructor then simply calls through to that constructor with an instance of `Foo` instantiated in the normal fashion.

```
public BarController() {
    this(new Foo());
}

@TestVisible
private BarController(Foo fooProperty) {
    this.fooProperty = fooProperty;
}
```

Unit tests then call the private constructor, and integration tests call the public constructor.

`Foo` could be an interface rather than a concrete type.